# onActivityResult not respecting the RESULT_OK through IF condition

Tags: java, android

I'm getting the *FirstConnection* class from the *MainActivity* class thanks to the baseline code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,FirstConnection.class) ;
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_INITILIZATION);
```

Once the activity of the *FirstConnection* class is finished, I use the following code to come back to the *MainActivity* class :

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
finish();
```

Then in the *MainActivity* class I use this code:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_INITILIZATION) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {  //  <= !! Problem HERE !!

           // code

        }
        if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

           // code

        }
    }
    else
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

**My problem is :** when i come back to the *MainActivity* class with **resultCode == RESULT_OK**, there is no way, my code doesn't go inside of the **IF condition** despite this condition is **true**!

I really don't understand, nad I'm sure that **resultCode == RESULT_OK** because I have checked in DEBUG mode.

Is there somobody having the similar issue?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I post the both class content.

*MainActivity*

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements NamesAdapterListener{

    private int REQUEST_CODE_INITILIZATION = 2 ; 


    private List<TitleList> listExisting ;
    private SQliteHelper db ;
    private TextView titleV;

    private CheckBox checkPartage;
    private CheckBox checkLocal;
    private EditText input;
    private LinearLayout layout;

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


//        boolean resultInitilization = appInitialization();
//        if (resultInitilization == false){
//          Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,FirstConnection.class) ;
//          startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_INITILIZATION);
//        }      

        /**
         * Opening of the database
         */
        db = new SQliteHelper( this ) ;


        /**
         * Initialization of the local database for the 1st time of use
         */
        db.Initialized();
        if (!db.getInitialized()){
            db.setInitialized();

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,FirstConnection.class) ;
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_INITILIZATION);

        }
        else{


            /**
             * Get the name of the existing lists
             */
            listExisting = db.getTitleSQliteHelper();  

            /**
             * Create an ArrayAdapter for the list's names
             */
            ArrayAdapterListNames listExistingAdapter = new ArrayAdapterListNames(this,listExisting) ;


            /**
             * Ecoute des évènements sur votre liste
             */
            listExistingAdapter.addListener(this);

            /**
             * 1) Implement the ListView containing the list of TextView
             * 2) registerForContextMenu => to display a pop-up menu after a long click on a the 
             * content of the ListView (TextView) 
             */
            ListView listNames = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListViewMain);
            registerForContextMenu(listNames);

            /**
             * Initialisation de la liste avec les données
             */
            listNames.setAdapter(listExistingAdapter);


            /**
             * Bouton pour ouverture nouvelle liste
             */
            final Button buttonsuiv = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnnewliste);
            buttonsuiv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                /**
                 * Dialog window to ask if the user wants to create a new list
                 */
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

                    // Instantiate the xml file
                    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(MainActivity.this.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) mInflater.inflate( R.layout.dialogbox_main_activity , null) ;

                    input = (EditText)layout.findViewById(R.id.titleSet);
                    checkPartage = (CheckBox)layout.findViewById(R.id.partage);
                    checkLocal = (CheckBox)layout.findViewById(R.id.local);

                    alert.setTitle("Création d'une nouvelle liste");
                    alert.setMessage("Tapez le nom de la nouvelle liste:");

                    // Set an EditText view to get user input 
                    final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                    alert.setView(layout);

                    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                          String value = input.getText().toString() ;
                          // Do something with value!

                          if ( checkPartage.isChecked() ){

                              Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListingArticlesDropb.class);
                              intent.putExtra("Title",value);
                              startActivity(intent);

                          }
                          else if ( checkLocal.isChecked() ){
                              Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListingArticles.class);
                              intent.putExtra("Title",value);
                              startActivity(intent);
                          }

                      }
                    });

                    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        dialog.cancel();

                      }
                    });

                    alert.show();


                  }
            });

        }


    }


    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_INITILIZATION) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

                int i2 = 1 ;
//              applicationWithSharedData();

            }
            else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                int i1 = 1 ;

//              applicationNoSharedData();

            }
        }
        else
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }




    /**
     * Creation of a contextual menu
     */
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {  
            super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo); 
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            menu.setHeaderTitle("Désirez-vous supprimer la liste?");  
//          menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Action 1");  
//          menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Action 2");  
        }  

    /**
     * Action activated when a menu's item is selected
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.yes_delete:


                /**
                 * Delete the list from the database
                 */
                db.deleteListArticle(listExisting.get(info.position).id);
                Log.d("onContextItemSelected => Numéro de l'ID:",String.valueOf(info.targetView.getId()) );

                /**
                 * Delete the title list from the screen
                 */
                Log.d("onContextItemSelected","Le switch fonctionne!");
                listExisting.remove(info.position);
                ArrayAdapterListNames listExistingAdapter = new ArrayAdapterListNames(this,listExisting) ;      
                listExistingAdapter.addListener(this);

                ListView listNames = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListViewMain);
                registerForContextMenu(listNames);

                listNames.setAdapter(listExistingAdapter);


                return true;

            case R.id.no_delete:
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


    public void onRestart(){
        super.onRestart();

        /**
         * Get the name of the existing lists
         */
        listExisting = db.getTitleSQliteHelper(); 

       /**
        * Create an ArrayAdapter for the list's names
        */
       ArrayAdapterListNames listExistingAdapter = new ArrayAdapterListNames(this,listExisting) ;


       /**
        * Ecoute des évènements sur votre liste
        */
       listExistingAdapter.addListener(this);

       /**
        * Récupération du composant ListView
        */
       ListView listNames = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListViewMain);

       /**
        * Initialisation de la liste avec les données
        */
       listNames.setAdapter(listExistingAdapter);

    }



    @Override
    public void onClickNom(TitleList item, int position) {

        if (item.TYPE_CONNECTION.equalsIgnoreCase("local")){

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListingArticles.class);
            intent.putExtra("Title",item.nom);  
            startActivity(intent);

        }
        else if (item.TYPE_CONNECTION.equalsIgnoreCase("dropbox")){

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ListingArticlesDropb.class);
            intent.putExtra("Title",item.nom);  
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    }
}
```

*FirstConnection*

```
public class FirstConnection extends Activity {


    final private String APP_KEY = **APP_KEY** ;
    final private String APP_SECRET = **APP_SECRET** ;

    static final int REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX = 0;  // This value is up to you

    private DbxAccountManager mAccountManager ;
    private DbxDatastoreManager mDatastoreManager;
    private DbxAccount account ;


    private SQliteHelper db ;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_first_connection);


        Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_first_connection) ;
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Set up the account manager
                mAccountManager = DbxAccountManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext(), APP_KEY, APP_SECRET);   


                // Set up the datastore manager
                if (mAccountManager.hasLinkedAccount()) {
                    try {
                        // Use Dropbox datastores
                        mDatastoreManager = DbxDatastoreManager.forAccount(mAccountManager.getLinkedAccount());

                        gatherData();

                    } catch (DbxException.Unauthorized e) {
                        System.out.println("Account was unlinked remotely");
                    }


                }
                if (mDatastoreManager == null) {
                    // Account isn't linked yet, use local datastores
                    mDatastoreManager = DbxDatastoreManager.localManager(mAccountManager);              

                    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(FirstConnection.this);
                    alert.setTitle("Connection à Dropbox");
                    alert.setMessage("L'initialisation de l'application sert à vous synchroniser avec l'espace de données partagées.\r\n"
                            + "Souhaitez-vous synchroniser votre application?");

                    alert.setPositiveButton("Oui", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                        mAccountManager.startLink((Activity)FirstConnection.this, REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX);

                      }
                    });

                    alert.setNegativeButton("Non", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                          Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                          setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
                          finish();


                      }
                    });


                    alert.show();
                }

            }



        });


    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_LINK_TO_DBX) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                account = mAccountManager.getLinkedAccount();
                Toast.makeText(this, "onActivityResult", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                try {
                    // Migrate any local datastores to the linked account
                    mDatastoreManager.migrateToAccount(account);
                    // Now use Dropbox datastores
                    mDatastoreManager = DbxDatastoreManager.forAccount(account);

                    gatherData();

                } catch (DbxException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                // Link failed or was cancelled by the user
            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }


    }


    private void gatherData(){

        db = new SQliteHelper( this ) ;
        Set<DbxDatastoreInfo> datastorePresent = null ;

        try {
            datastorePresent = mDatastoreManager.listDatastores();
        } catch (DbxException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        Iterator<DbxDatastoreInfo> datastoreLoop = datastorePresent.iterator() ;
        while (datastoreLoop.hasNext()){

            TitleList tit = new TitleList(datastoreLoop.next().id) ;
            tit.setConnectDropbox();
            db.addLists(tit);

        }

        mDatastoreManager.shutDown();

          Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
          boolean syncOK = true ;
          returnIntent.putExtra("result", syncOK) ;
          setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
          finish();
//        startActivity(returnIntent);
    }



}
```

Comment: have you check value of resultCode ?

Comment: Just a suggestion, you better use "else" if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED). And just for "testing", try to create an opposite selection. So if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) first and then else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK). Try to debug again to make sure the result is OK

Comment: @Haresh Chhelana : yes I have checked, the value of resultCode = -1 what is normally expected.

Comment: @Blaze Tama: I gonna try what you mention and I'll give you news!

Comment: Maybe try to setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);

Comment: Are you passing any extras to your Intent when you use setResult()?

Comment: @BlazeTama : I have tried your test but nothing has changed I have still the same crazy problem. With my debugger I'have got **resultCode  = -1** and no way, my code is not going into the condition `(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)`

Comment: @joao2fast4u : I have updated my question to let you see the whole content of my code. Maybe there is a mistake that I have not raised.

Comment: Use always Activity.RESULT_OK and Activity.RESULT_CANECELLED instead of just RESULT_OK. If your Intent has no extras, use only setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK); and then finish();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this method on **MainActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case REQUSET_CODE_YOUR:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // write here code via **RESULT_OK**
        }
        break;

    default: // none of these
        break;
    }
}
```

And after then FirstConnection screen as par write to code this whatever you need to method.

```
setResult(RESULT_OK); // important
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why but the switch condition is working.

Answer (score 0):

you have mentioned in the first that
**Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);**

is used in FirstConnection class,and in the above FirstConnection code i dint find it where have you used it, It is completely proper if you have used it. It is logical if the condition is true it continues, the only mistake can happen in "if" condition if you have used "=" instead of "==" ,which assigns instead condition check.